# Passing more parameters into callback function

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, parameter-passing, lodash

I use lodash `_.forIn`, it has a callback with key and value.

```
_.forIn({...}, callback);

function callback(key, value) {...}
```

Is there a way to pass a third parameter to that function?

Comment: what do you want to the third parameter to do?

Comment: I have 2 objects I want to iterate and make changes to, but the changes need to be slightly different.

Comment: You can add another parameter to it, however it will depend on lodash `_.forIn` to call your function with an extra argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `HOF` (Higher-Order Function) to avoid writing a separate callback with almost the same body.

```
function createCallback(yourParameter){
    return function(key, value){
        if(yourParameter === 'Something'){
           //doSomething different;
        } else if(yourParameter === 'Something else'){
           //doSomethingElse
        }
    }
}

var cb1 = createCallback('Something');
var cb2 = createCallback('Something else');

_.forIn({...}, cb1);
_.forIn({...}, cb2);
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but is there a way to just pass the parameter directly without the if?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with `yourParameter`, in my example I just used it to do something different depending on the value of it, but you can use the parameter as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Use [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) for this.

```
function log() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

var func = _.partial(log, 'hello');

func('world');
// → [ "hello", "world" ]
```